# How can I invoke function after screen mounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In the home screen, I have a function that's getting the 'user type: Paid / UnPaid' from API,

So in this screen, I have a drawer inside it a user can navigate to sign in screen, so after user sign in I navigate him back to Home screen

but in this case, the Home screen is already mounted that's mean userIsPaid function is already invoked for the first time, so I want to recheck if this account is paid or not again "invoke userisPaid()"?

because in Bottom Tab, I render a new tab conditionally based on user type and it does not work because I'm not rechecking user type.

Code

Root.js

```
const BottomTabStack = createBottomTabNavigator();
function BottomTabs() {
  const isPaid = useSelector(state => state.userIsPaid.isPaid);

...
 <BottomTabStack.Navigator
      lazy={false}
      tabBar={props => <TabBar {...props} />}
      >
...
 {isPaid && (
        <BottomTabStack.Screen
          name="Library"
          component={YourLibraryStackScreen}
        />
      )}
    </BottomTabStack.Navigator>
}
```

Home.js

```
  userIsPaid = async () => {
    try {
      const {token} = this.props;
      let AuthStr = `Bearer ${token}`;
      let response = await API.get('/profile', {
        headers: {Authorization: AuthStr},
      });
      const {account} = response.data.data;
      console.log('account??', account);
      account === 'unpaid'
        ? this.props.isUserPaid(false)
        : this.props.isUserPaid(true);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

componentDidMount() {
    const {token} = this.props;
    token && this.userIsPaid();
 }
```

SignIn.js

```
  sendData = async data => {
    // this.setState({loading: true});
    try {
      let response = await API.post('/google', data);
      // this.setState({loading: false});
      let {
        data: {
          data: {
            response: {token},
          },
        },
      } = response;

      this.props.dispatch(saveToken(token));
      this.props.dispatch(isLoginFunc(true));
      this.props.navigation.push('BottomTabNavigator'); // bottom navigation 'home,about....'
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Your isPaid state is in the redux store right ? Why dont you use the data in the redux store to check if the person has paid or not and use it to do a conditional rendering ?

Comment: @Muljayan If i understand u well, yes I'm already doing it!

Comment: @Muljayan Can you explain more what exactly you mean?

Comment: You can get the `isPaid` in your home page using `  const isPaid = useSelector(state => state.userIsPaid.isPaid);`?

Comment: @Muljayan Hmm, just to explain the issue, after user open the app at the first time I navigate hem to home screen right, in a home screen I call a function that checks if a user is paid or not (from API) in a home screen I have a drawer after user open it and click to sign in I navigate hem to sign in screen after he signs in I navigate back to the home screen but in this case, the home is mounted before and check the user is paid is invoked so I want to recheck again to dispatch an action to change isPaid status from unpaid to paid and based on it I render new tab conditionally

Comment: @Muljayan are you got it?

Comment: So when you come back to home page you want to check if the state is paid and then do some logic ? you can try to use https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop#isfocused this prop if youre using react navigation. You can also use componentDidUpdate life cycle to detect changes when you come back to the home page.

Comment: @Muljayan If i use `isfocused` should i put it in render method?

Comment: This comment section is long and its asking me to move to chat... So I'd suggest that you look into how `componentDidUpdate` works and you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Using `shouldComponentUpdate()` lifecycle method mybe useful.
Use `shouldComponentUpdate()` to let React know if a component’s output is not affected by the current change in *state* or *props*. The default behavior is to re-render on every *state* change, and in the vast majority of cases, you should rely on the default behavior.

`shouldComponentUpdate()` is invoked before rendering when new *props* or *state* are being received. Defaults to `true`. This method is not called for the initial render or when `forceUpdate()` is used.

Comment: Thanks for replying, But I'm using `PureComponent` in Home screen!

Comment: Your Home.js is a class component.

Comment: Yes it is, class component extend pureComponent, I guess I can't use shouldComponentUpdate in it?

Comment: You can use lifecycle methods in a class component and useEffect()  hook in a functional component.

Comment: Yes I know.. But if I use shouldComponentUpdate() in pureComponent I got this warning as usual, shouldComponentUpdate should not be used when extending React.PureComponent. Please extend React.Component if shouldComponentUpdate is used. So now other ways to handle it without use shouldComponentUpdate() lifecycle?

Comment: You should refactor your code and transform all your components to the functional component.